# About Fermat's last theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If
$p$
is an odd prime and
$p < x < y < z$
are integers such that
$$x^{p} + y^{p} = z^{p},\ \ p \mid y,$$
would it hold that
$$z-x = p$$

If possible, I wish to know whether there is any paper proving this.

Comment: Note that if we assume we have a solution $x_0^p + y_0^p = z_0^p$ and put $x=Qx_0, y=Qy_0,z=Qz_0$ then $x^p + y^p = z^p$ is also a solution for any $Q$ including $Q=p$. So the answer is no - it does not imply $z-x=p$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Winther. But how is $z_{o} - x_{o}$?

Comment: You might also want to ask: if $p|y$, but $p\not| z,x$ do we have $p | (z-x)$. The answer here is yes as $0 \equiv y^p - z^p \equiv z-p$ mod $p$ from Fermats little theorem. So in general all you can say is that $z-x$ is divisible by $p$.

Comment: Ah Ha, thank you. But I myself have observed these facts. Indeed, Stewart in 1977 published in Mathematika the paper ``A note on the Fermat equation'', which gives the general form of $x+y, z-x, z-y$ under rather weak assumptions.  The problem is I cannot get this paper for now and I cannot recall his results well enough at the present!

Comment: http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/7429/7429A.pdf

Comment: Since the equation have no solutions, the claim indeed hold, vacuously.

Comment: Dear Winther, thank you so much. That's extremely helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll play around and see what your assumption of $p|y$ can lead to.

If $p | y$,
then $p | z^p-x^p$.
Letting
$z = x+w$,
$z^p-x^p
=(x+w)^p-x^p
=\sum_{k=0}^p \binom{p}{k} x^k w^{p-k} - x^p
=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \binom{p}{k} x^k w^{p-k}
$.
Since
$p | \binom{p}{k}$
for $1 \le k \le p-1$,
$p | w^p$
so $p | w$.

Let $w = p^mv$ where 
$m \ge 1$ and
$p \not \mid v$.

I will assume that
$p \not \mid x$,
or else $p \mid z$
and we could divide $p$ out
until
$p \not \mid x$ 
or 
$p \not \mid y$.

$\begin{array}\\
y^p
&=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \binom{p}{k} x^k w^{p-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \binom{p}{k} x^k (v p^m)^{p-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{p} \binom{p}{k} x^{p-k} (v p^m)^k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{p} \binom{p}{k} x^{p-k} v^k p^{mk}\\
&=p^m\sum_{k=1}^{p} \binom{p}{k} x^{p-k} v^k p^{m(k-1)}\\
&=p^m(x^{p-1}v+\sum_{k=2}^{p} \binom{p}{k} x^{p-k} v^k p^{m(k-1)})\\
\end{array}
$

The first term
($x^{p-1}v$)
is not divisible by $p$
and all the terms in the sum are,
so
$p^m \mid \mid y^p$
(i.e., 
$p^m \mid y^p$
and
$p^{m+1} \not \mid y^p$
).
If
$y = p^a b$
where $p \not \mid b$
(I'm running out of letters)
$p^m \mid \mid y^p$
means
$p^m \mid \mid p^{ap}b^p$
so
$m = ap$
or $p \mid m$.

Therefore
$p^p \mid y$.

However,
I do not see how to 
take this further
and,
in particular,
I do not see how this can imply
that $p = w$.

Comment: You'd also need to assume that $x$, $y$ and $z$ are  relatively prime, otherwise you could just multiply the whole by $p^n$ and have that divide the difference

Comment: Yep, I do. (characters added to make it happy)